# Parsing of rows in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame which I want to parse based on relatives column

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("abc","def","ghi","klm"),
             Relatives = c("Mother & Father","Mother and brother","Husband,wife,Sister in law and Daughter","Self"))



Name                               Relatives
abc                         Mother & Father
def                      Mother and brother
ghi             Husband,wife,Sister in law and Daughter
klm                                    Self
```

Final output

```
Name               Relatives
abc                 Mother
abc                 Father
def                 Mother
def                 brother
ghi                 Husband
ghi                 wife
ghi                 Sister in law
ghi                 daughter
klm                 self
```

Any help is useful, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty in base R:

```
tmp <- strsplit(df$Relatives, '\\&|,| and ')
data.frame(Name = rep(df$Name, lengths(tmp)), Relatives = trimws(unlist(tmp)))
#   Name     Relatives
# 1  abc        Mother
# 2  abc        Father
# 3  def        Mother
# 4  def       brother
# 5  ghi       Husband
# 6  ghi          wife
# 7  ghi Sister in law
# 8  ghi      Daughter
# 9  klm          Self
```

Same logic with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, strsplit(Relatives, '\\&|,| and '), by = Name
   ][, Relatives := trimws(V1)][, V1 := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr::separate_rows` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Relatives, sep = '&|\\band\\b|,') %>%
  mutate(Relatives = trimws(Relatives))

#  Name  Relatives    
#  <chr> <chr>        
#1 abc   Mother       
#2 abc   Father       
#3 def   Mother       
#4 def   brother      
#5 ghi   Husband      
#6 ghi   wife         
#7 ghi   Sister in law
#8 ghi   Daughter     
#9 klm   Self
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse and tidytext:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "klm"),
  Relatives = c(
    "Mother & Father",
    "Mother and brother",
    "Husband,wife,Sister in law and Daughter",
    "Self"
  )
)

df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>%
  unnest_tokens(
    text,
    Relatives,
    token = "regex",
    pattern = "\\&| and |,",
    to_lower = FALSE
  ) %>%
  mutate(text = str_trim(text))
```

Output:

```
  Name          text
1  abc        Mother
2  abc        Father
3  def        Mother
4  def       brother
5  ghi       Husband
6  ghi          wife
7  ghi Sister in law
8  ghi      Daughter
9  klm          Self
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
df %>% 
separate(Relatives, sep = "( & |,| and )", into = letters[1:3]) %>% 
pivot_longer(2:4, values_to = "Relatives",values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
select(Name, Relatives)
```

and you'll get this:

```
Name  Relatives
  <chr> <chr>    
1 abc   Mother   
2 abc   Father   
3 def   Mother   
4 def   and      
5 def   brother  
6 ghi   Husband  
7 ghi   wife     
8 ghi   and      
9 klm   self
```